# How to make the Eclipse content assist for common CSS available everywhere?

Tags: css, eclipse, content-assist

In my Eclipse project I have a template.html which is the base template for all the other html files. In that template.html, I can access all of the CSS classes via content assist, because I included all of the CSS stuff in there.

Naturally, I don't do very much in the template.html, so that doesn't help at all. But the content assist doesn't work in any other file, unless I include all of the css files again - which seems like the wrong approach to me.

Is there any way to let Eclipse know or assume that I can use that CSS anywhere without problems, because I included it at some point higher in the template-tree?

I googled for quite some time now but I can't seem to find the right words to search for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

I somehow missed the "CSS" entry in Window -> Preferences. There you can activate "Search CSS id and class in all CSS files (if no link)?". Make sure that under "Configure Project Specific Settings..." in that same view the project specific settings for the relevant project are disabled. Then content assist will provide you with suggestions while typing.

Also, you need to disable warnings for unknown CSS classes, because these warnings and the content assist don't seem to work together very well. To do that, got to Window -> Preferences -> Web -> HTML Files -> Web Resources and open  the CSS submenu in the view. There you need to set both "Unkown CSS class" and "Unknown CSS ID" to "Ignore".